# Off-the-shelf tools for humongous file transfer over WAN?

Tags: software-rec, file-transfer

I need to transfer a couple of 20 GB files over the internet. There is exactly one sender and one receiver.

I would like a tool that can not only send this direct, **without uploading** it anywhere first, but also verify the file by parts and re-download only the corrupt parts like BitTorrent does (which also implies resumability since this will take a couple of weeks).

Can someone recommend a tool capable of this?

**Edit** Forgot to mention: the sender has no open incoming ports, so can't accept connections.

Comment: That edit complicates things, in which case you may have to use the VNC method @Paul outlined below, initiated from the sender's PC.

Comment: I answered before your edit. Do you mean there are no other open ports other than Port 80 (HTTP)? Or there are no open ports period, no internet connection, etc.? In which case this is obviously impossible and I'm hoping you mean that only Port 80 is unblocked, in which case my solution may cause issues as you need a port other than 80 to be open.

Comment: @Paul your solution is fine, I will give it a go. The sender can't accept incoming connections, but it can of course initiate outgoing ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way I know to do this is [ultraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/features/filetransfer.html).

> Ultr@VNC features an embedded File Transfer with intuitive Graphical User Interface allowing for easy file copy between local and remote computers.
>
> - Compression: Files are compressed on the fly during transfers, ensuring optimal bandwidth utilization
> - Resume: Interrupted transfers can be resumed, thus only the missing parts of the files are resent
> - Delta Transfer: only the changed parts of the files are resent
> - Transfers are asynchronous if wanted:
>
>   - When the File transfer GUI Window is visible there are no screen updates, so the speed for file transfers is max.
>   - When File transfer GUI Window is minimized screen updates and file transfers occur in parallel.
> - Display of progress percentage during transfers
> - Directory Transfer
> - Uses the current Ultr@VNC connection
> - Optional User Impersonation option, limiting remote file system access to identified Windows ™ users only

Answer (score 2):

If you can split the 20 GB file into smaller chunks (e.g. by using WinRAR split volumes), you can upload them using box-standard FTP or similar; the smaller you make the chunks, the less data will need to be retransmitted if any one of them breaks (which you can check using WinRAR’s “test” command).

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't BitTorrent actually be the appropriate choice in this situation? As long as YOU have open outgoing ports, he should be able to connect to you and receive data.

Just grab a BitTorrent client (I recommend [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/), though on Windows you'll need [something different](http://www.utorrent.com/)), use it to generate a `.torrent` file for the files you want to transfer, and aim it at the [OpenBitTorrent](http://openbittorrent.com/) tracker. Make sure your ports are open, email the `.torrent` file to your friend and then wait 4-6 weeks for delivery.

I was under the impression that the reason open ports are usually required for BitTorrent was that in order to acquire lots of download streams from the tracker, you need to be a good citizen and upload data as well, which requires open ports. For a private torrent with one seed and one peer this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I have tried this before. BitTorrent is atrociously bad with a single seed and a single peer. It constantly drops the download, and never goes at full speed. eMule worked fine last time. It's a bit annoying to have to encrypt the file first though.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be faster to send a hard drive via UPS or FedEx. You could even abuse a retail store's return policy if you really needed to, though I don't recommend doing that.